# this.method.name is undefined after typescript transpilation

Tags: typescript

## Description

this.method.name is undefined after typescript transpilation

## Example

When I run this code

```
class MyClass {
  myMethod() {
    // this.myMethod.name == undefined
    console.log(this.myMethod.name) 
  }
}

new MyClass().myMethod()
// "" instead of "myMethod"
```

I expect to see the name of my method in console but I see empty string instead because `this.myMethod.name` is undefined

tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "ESNext",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## In Short

Use newer target (`> ES2015`) in typescript compiler options, for example `ES2022`

## Description

This problem is related to the target you have set in typescript compiler options.
[There is an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5611) about this and there I have found out that you should set newer target to make your methods have names

## Examples

### New Target (ES2022)

#### Description

[This playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1oFt6wFMAXACwHsATACgEp0ttpgyA7CMkAgOhDIHMqpAJYQueQqUpcWYHARoMAvhmUYWBAO5wkKCLTH5i5ajSA) shows us that name of the method is its name

*Note: there is bug with playground - when you enter you can possibly see the wrong target in config. You can change it to any target to try check targets itself*

#### Source Code

```
class MyClass {
  myMethod() {
    console.log(this.myMethod.name)
  }
}

new MyClass().myMethod()
```

**Output**

```
"use strict";
class MyClass {
    myMethod() {
        console.log(this.myMethod.name);
    }
}
new MyClass().myMethod();
```

**Compiler Options**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ESNext",
  }
}
```

### Old Target (ES5)

#### Description

[This playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1oFt6wFMAXACwHsATACgEp0ttpgyA7CMkAgOhDIHMqpAJYQueQqUpcWYHARoMAvhmUYWBAO5wkKCLTH5i5ajSA) shows us that name of the method is undefined

*Note: there is bug with playground - when you enter you can possibly see the wrong target in config. You can change it to any target to try check targets itself*

#### Source Code

```
class MyClass {
  myMethod() {
    console.log(this.myMethod.name)
  }
}

new MyClass().myMethod()
```

**Output**

Take a look at at this output code! There is an anonymous function instead of named!

```
"use strict";
var MyClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    // Look here! We have anonymous function instead of named!
    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function () {
        console.log(this.myMethod.name);
    };
    return MyClass;
}());
new MyClass().myMethod();
```

**Compiler Options**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "ESNext",
  }
}
```

Comment: "Use newer target in typescript compiler options, for example ES3" I think that needs to be "> ES2015"

Comment: @AlexWayne You are right, it is a typography mistake, I actually wanted to write ES2022 there. I will fix it right now